# when I push my code on github , Pushing to Git returning Error Code

Tags: git, github

Can't finish GitHub sharing process. Successfully created project  on GitHub, but initial commit failed:

```
Please tell me who you are. Run
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: empty ident name (for <(NULL)>) not allowed
```

during executing

```
git -c core.quotepath=false commit -m "Initial commit" --
```

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands git told you. Set name and email:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```